# How to fetch data from Amazon mysql database to localhost(xammp)?

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, xampp, localhost

I need to sync two websites. One is online and another is local. How can I fetch database data from Amazon server to localhost(xammp)?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

MySQL server on your localhost can connect to Amazon mysql database if you have open port 3306 on Amazon server. You can setup replication between Amazon server and localhost for live sync.

Otherwise you can setup a script which copies the binary logs from Amazon server and applies them on localhost.